# Round just decimal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, format, decimal, rounding

I have a value like that:

> 20.93

I'd like to round it to

> 20.90

How can I do that in Javascript ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the number by 10, round it and then divide the number by 10:

```
var result = Math.round(20.93 * 10) / 10
```

Comment: I think dividing by 10 afterwards adds extra loss of precision

Comment: @wuhounited He wants the output to be `20.90`. `20.90` is `20.9` (at least in javascript `alert(20.90)`)

Comment: @brian `toFixed(2)` return `20.93`

Comment: First I did what you said, it gave me "20.9", so I used .toFixed(2) to print "20.90"

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

*number*.toFixed(1);

Answer (score 0):

```
var num= 20.93
num = Math.floor(num * 10) / 10; // 20.9
num = Math.ceil(num * 10) / 10;  //21
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want the trailing zero. None of the answers give you that. It has to be a String to have the trailing zero.

```
function my_round(x){
  return Number(x).toFixed(1) + '0';
}
```

If you don't care about the trailing zero and you want a Number (not String), then here's another way to round to decimal places in JavaScript. This rounds to decimal place d.

```
function my_round(x, d){
  return Number( Number(x).toFixed(d) );
}
```

You would do

```
my_round('20.93', 1);
```

or

```
my_round(20.93, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can set** `toFixed(1)`. **but set value = 20.96** then **you have 21 and not 20.90**;

BUT with my function always will be 20.90 than 20.93 like 20.98/97/96/95...

```
<script>

    var num = 20.93;

function vround(num) { // CREATE BY ROGERIO DE MORAES

    var Dif = (num.toFixed(2)-num.toFixed(1)).toFixed(2); 
    Dif = Dif * 100; 
    if(Dif <= -1) {

    var n = num.toFixed(2) - 0.05;
    vround(n);
     } else {
     var n = num.toFixed(1)+0;
    console.log(n);
     }
}

vround(num);

</script>
```

*I create this function for get you value, but can change, if you wanna more forms.*

Comment: **set into vround('you values / variable'); and get you value...**